# What's the correct way to extract tf-idf topfeatures by document?

Tags: r, quanteda

Assume we have a tf-idf weighted dfm from a corpus of 10K rather small documents.

What's the `quanteda` way of extracting the top feature, i.e., max tf-idf values by document? 
I do want the entire corpus to be the reference when computing tf-idf. Something along the lines of

```
topfeatures(some_dfm_tf_idf, n =3, decreasing = TRUE, groups ="id")
```

returns an appropriate list. Yet it takes quite some time for something that is basically sorted out already at this point. Given that quanteda performs so well in everything I did so far, I am suspect I am might be doing something wrong here.

Maybe this is somewhat related to this discussion on github (https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues/1646) and the example workaround that @Astelix shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`topfeatures()` is exactly the way to go.  I'm not sure why you are stating that it "takes quite some time", or what your "id" docvar is, but the following is the correct and most efficient way to get a list of the top scored features in your dfm (regardless of the weighting).

The result is a named list where the names are the docnames, and each element is a named numeric vector where the element name is the feature label.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.5.2

some_dfm_tf_idf <- dfm(data_corpus_irishbudget2010)[1:5, ] %>%
  dfm_tfidf()

topfeatures(some_dfm_tf_idf, n = 1, groups = docnames(some_dfm_tf_idf))
## $`Lenihan, Brian (FF)`
## details 
## 5.57116 
## 
## $`Bruton, Richard (FG)`
## confront 
##  5.59176 
## 
## $`Burton, Joan (LAB)`
## lenihan 
## 4.19382 
## 
## $`Morgan, Arthur (SF)`
##    sinn 
## 5.59176 
## 
## $`Cowen, Brian (FF)`
## dividend 
##  4.19382
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the type of confirmation I hoped for. I got 12K documents with about 30K features. `dfm_tfidf()` was blazing fast, then for no apparent reason `topfeatures()` took minutes despite the fact that the score was computed already and this should be a matter of `sort(score)`. Maybe this was just the wrong expectation / a local problem. Btw: This was really one of the few cases in which I did not see immediately what the way to go was /w {quanteda}. The approach and documentation is just that good. To me easily one of the best ecosystems that came up in the R world more recently.

Comment: Thanks!! I realized why this method is so slow, so added another answer. I'd be happy for anyone to find an even faster way!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. However, when I try to run this I always get the following error: will not group a weighted dfm; use force = TRUE to override. When I try this, I get the output that force = TRUE is an unsupported argument. Do you have an idea where the problem is?

Comment: Nevermind, the solution described by Astelix on Github works for me: https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues/1646#issuecomment-472733219 Thanks anyway!

Comment: The second method below, `get_top_feature()`, does not have this problem. But I've proposed a fix for this warning in any case. https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/pull/2033

Answer (score 2):

`topfeatures()` is somewhat slow because it sorts each feature and then returns the top value.  A more efficient way to get just the top valued feature in each document is to use `max.col`.  Here's the method and a comparison (putting the return in a list of the same format as the `topfeatures()` answer).

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.5.2

data(data_corpus_sotu, package = "quanteda.corpora")
dfmat <- dfm(data_corpus_sotu) %>%
  dfm_tfidf()

# alternative using max.col
get_top_feature <- function(x) {
  topfeature_index <- max.col(x, "first")
  result <- mapply(function(a, b) {
    l <- as.numeric(x[a, b])
    names(l) <- featnames(x)[b]
    l
  },
  seq_len(ndoc(x)), topfeature_index,
  SIMPLIFY = FALSE
  )
  names(result) <- docnames(x)
  result
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  topfeatures = topfeatures(dfmat, n = 1, groups = docnames(dfmat)),
  maxcol = get_top_feature(dfmat),
  times = 20, unit = "relative"
)
## Unit: relative
##         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##  topfeatures 2.085184 2.113136 2.069444 2.104166 2.032536 1.987218    20
##       maxcol 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ken's `get_top_feature()` you might not only be interested in the "top" terms but also in the terms with the 2nd-heighest weighting in a tfidf-dtm. It took me some time to figure it out, so I thought it might be helpful in general.

```
get_scnd_feature <- function(x) {
topfeature_index <- max.col(x, 'first')
scndfeature_index <- max.col(replace(x, cbind(seq_len(nrow(x)), topfeature_index), -Inf), 'first')
  result <- mapply(function(a, b) {
    l <- as.numeric(x[a, b])
    names(l) <- featnames(x)[b]
    l
  },
  seq_len(ndoc(x)), scndfeature_index,
  SIMPLIFY = FALSE
  )
  names(result) <- docnames(x)
  result
}
scndterm_tfidf <- get_scnd_feature(dtmtfidf)
```

You can check the result by comparing the weights:

```
maxn <- function(n) function(x) order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[n]
scndtermcount <- apply(dtmtfidf, 1, function(x)x[maxn(2)(x)])
```